# Given a matrix contained in a text file, print all the columns

Tags: shell, matrix, text-processing

Let's suppose I have a textfile with a matrix:

```
0   1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24
```

I want to print all the columns in this way:

```
0 5 10 15 20
1 6 11 16 21
2 7 12 17 22
3 8 13 18 23
4 9 14 19 24
```

How can I do that in shell script or another programming language?

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a homework assignment.
If that is the case, you must look for the answer in order to learn.
I will give you some tips

https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-file-into-an-array-of-bytes/
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-transpose-matrix

With this you can put together a puzzle.